# How do I get a custom button to redirect me to a page in apex oracle?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have created the following button for an interactive grid (IG) using `JavaScript Initialization Code` in the IG attributes section.

```
function(config) {
    var $ = apex.jQuery,
        toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
        lastToolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions4"),
        assembleButton = {
            type: "BUTTON",
            hot: false,
            icon: "fa fa-send u-info-text",
            iconBeforeLabel: true,
            action: "assemble-as"
        };
    lastToolbarGroup.controls.push( assembleButton );
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    
    // this is how actions are added
    config.initActions = function(actions) {
        actions.add({
            name: "assemble-as",
            label: "Assemble as ...",
            action: function(event, focusElement) { apex.event.trigger("#hiddenAssembleAsButton", "hidden_assemble_as_button_click"); }
        });
    }
    
    return config;
}
```

Then I created the `hiddenAssembleAsButton` using that name as the `Static ID` under advanced.

The button is defined by a dynamic action `Hidden_Assemble_As_Button_Click` which is where I think I should be able to redirect the page, but I'm not sure.

It seems like the page redirect should happen in the `jQuery Selector` but I don't know what to put there or if that's the correct area to add the code.

I can add images if necessary but I feel like I've described this pretty well.

Comment: I can see the button, but clicking it doesn't do anything right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you need a button somewhere in the interactive grid, but you still like to use the declarative options APEX provides with basic buttons, like doing all the stuff like passing variable values, calculating checksums or opening a dialog when your target page is a model page. This can be difficult in pure javascript.

In this case, you can also just create a basic button, set it up all the way you like in the designer, then hide it using Advanced --> Custom Attributes:  `style="display:none"`. Also, set a static ID like `button1`.

[image]

Then, in your action, you can simply trigger a click on the button.

```
    actions.add({
        name: "assemble-as",
        label: "Assemble as ...",
        action: function(event, focusElement) { $('#button1').click(); }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button *does* something. It triggers an event called `hidden_assemble_as_button_click` binded to an id `#hiddenAssembleAsButton`. You want it to redirect. The simplest option is to do the redirect right in that code. Replace the `actions.add` block with this one:

```
        actions.add({
            name: "assemble-as",
            label: "Assemble as ...",
            action: function(event, focusElement) { window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"; }
        });
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I'm a little skeptical because apex has built in design to redirect to pages within the application. For example, if I were to use a built in button, I can just go to the attribute section and use it to redirect to whatever page I want. That's why I'm trying to reference the button in the code so that I can just use the built in button attributes. That may not be possible, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: You cannot reference or create a component of type "button" in an interactive grid. The architecture is different - an interactive grid is very does a lot of the work on the client side. The traditional built-in buttons are server side oriented.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am doing it this way. I have to write a script that designs the button and puts it where I want it. Then I can give the generic button a static ID and reference it in the script so that it works with the built in button attributes. That's what the other guy who answered got the credit. Thank you for your insight though.

Comment: Other solution is cleaner indeed